# Display a list from different site collection

Tags: list, site-collection, cross-site

In SP Online,is there a way to display a list from sitecollection A on sitecollection B?

Are there any ways that I create a new list in sitecollection B,using a workflow or any data-sync methods, can I copy over the data from sitecollection A to sitecollection B?

Answer (score 1):

you can use **SharePoint Content Search Web Part** will help you to achieve displaying a data from a site collection in another site.
for more details please check the below link

[Your Step by Step Guide to SharePoint Content Search Web Part](https://www.cmswire.com/information-management/your-step-by-step-guide-to-sharepoint-content-search-web-part/)

Comment: Saeed I tried Content Search web part,but using this webpart, I am able to display only the "Title" column from the other list, are there any ways to add more custom columns to the webpart view? For eg: I want to display the Status,Comments,Rating and Service columns along with the Title column in CSWP.Is it possible to add custom column to CSWP?

Comment: Saeed Are there any ways that i create a new list in sitecollection B,using a workflow or any data-sync methods, I can copy over the data from sitecollection A to sitecollection B?

Comment: @George Refer this link - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0c4458bf-3397-470d-a675-e90e260de624/content-search-webpart-showing-additional-columns?forum=sharepointgeneral

Answer (score 1):

Using SP Designer 2013 workflow, I was able to achieve what was required. I used the below 2 articles.

https://blog.portiva.nl/2016/11/03/sharepoint-designer-call-http-web-service-to-create-item-in-other-site-collection/

https://mysharepointexperiences.wordpress.com/2017/03/18/using-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-updatecreate-item-in-other-site-collection/

Unfortunately I am not able to update "People/Group" and "Hyperlink" columns by this method.